# qTip dynamic button with jQuery (currently using selectors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, qtip

Random elements throughout the page have an attribute named `qtip`.  I would like to find each one, and in the qTip `content` section, display the contents of the `qtip` attribute.

```
$("*[qtip]").qtip({
    content: $(this).attr("qtip"),
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout'
});
```

If I don't put the `$(this).attr("qtip")` and just put static text (e.g. "Test"), it works.  However, the `$(this)` is screwing it up.  I there another way to do it?  I'm not attached to selectors if there is another way to find all the elements with the `qtip` attribute.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.3.4, but I can update it if something fancy has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .each() function so "this" refers to each element.

```
$("*[qtip]").each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: $(this).attr("qtip"),
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout'
    });
});
```